# Find and Replace Regular Expression (NotePad++)

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I'm looking at a global search and replace within NotePad++ which will look for the following text...

```
date and %c
```

examples would be...

```
date +%m-%d%H:%M:%S%c
date +%m-%d%H%c:%M:%S
date +%c-%m-%d%H:%M:%S
```

etc.

I can find the string by searching for
    date (.)+%c
but I can't think for the life of me what the replacement would be. I want to replace %c with %z (or something else later on) and keep the remaining text.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(date.*?)%c
```

Replace by  :`$1%z`

Comment: Yeah, better. No need to capture what comes behind `%c`.

Comment: Both are good, this one is a little simpler, but both are good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can search for

```
date (.*?)%c(.*)
```

and replace it by

```
date $1%z$2
```

Output for your examples:

```
date +%m-%d%H:%M:%S%z
date +%m-%d%H%z:%M:%S
date +%z-%m-%d%H:%M:%S
```

Comment: Perfect, tried and tested and working perfectly. Simple when you know how, shame I don't!

Comment: Well, no problem. Glad what it helps.